# How to read from only one index and set the other one as write when searching an alias in ElasticSearch 7.6?

Tags: elasticsearch

I know it's possible to define two indices in an alias where one index has the `is_write_index` set to `true` while the other has it set to false -

```
POST /_aliases
{
    "actions" : [
        {
            "add" : {
                 "index" : "test_index_1",
                 "alias" : "my_alias",
                 "is_write_index": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

```
POST /_aliases
{
    "actions" : [
        {
            "add" : {
                 "index" : "test_index_2",
                 "alias" : "my_alias",
                 "is_write_index": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, I've defined two indices `test_index_1` and `test_index_2` where the first one is a write index while the second one isn't.

Now, I want to be able to query the `my_alias` in such a way that searches happen only on the `test_index_2` which has the `is_write_index` set to `false` while I write data to `test_index_1`, instead of reading from both the indices, which is the default behaviour. Meaning, I don't wish the search results come from the index where `is_write_index` is set to `true`.

Is this possible? I've tried setting `index.blocks.read` to `true` on the write index, but then search queries on the alias fail with an exception. Instead, I wish reads on the alias query only from that index which has the `is_write_index` set to `false`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not add a second alias?

Comment: @AlkisKalogeris I need to be able to read and write to the same alias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved using [filtered aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/indices-aliases.html#filtered).

The way you do this is you apply a custom filter while adding the write index to the alias. The `filter` property defines the `bool` condition based on which data is filtered on this index and presented as a new view of the dataset in this index. All search queries on this index happen on this new view that Elastic creates. So, if you want to avoid reading from the index you're currently writing to, apply a filter that is never satisfied across any documents in your dataset or an `exists` filter on some dummy field.

```
POST /_aliases
{
    "actions": [
    {
        "add": {
            "index": "test_index_2",
            "alias": "my_alias",
            "is_write_index": true,
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must_not": {
                        "exists": {
                            "field": "<field_that_always_exists_in_your_documents>"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

Once you're done writing the data, update the alias by removing the `filter` property to allow reads from both the indices.

Answer (score 1):

You are using this feature in an incorrect fashion. If you use alias for search, it will always attempt to read across all underlying indices. **is_write_index** is provided as feature to support rollover and index patterns, where writes are happening to 1 index, but reads happen across all indices with same alias or index pattern.

If your intent is to load data into one index, but allow application to continue to read from old index, when data loading is going on, you should use 2 separate alias - one for read and one for write and device a strategy to swap alias pointing to the indices, after your data loading is completed.

Comment: Not really sure about that. Writing to one alias and reading from another certainly seems like an anti-pattern to me.

Comment: No. Its not, if you are talking about full reload (which is what i have assumed). In such a case, its standard practice to load data on new index, while app continues to read data from current live index and once new data is available, we swap the alias so that its transparent to application reading data. But you haven't clearly explained what you are trying to achieve in the 1st place. What is your primary use case?

Comment: Note that I only use this while adding a new dataset. I'm trying to build the new index in the background while I continue servicing the reads from the old one. Eventually, this write index is going to be converted to a normal index after the writing has been done.

Comment: Our read and write workflows both need to write to the same alias.

Comment: So you still want to read from multiple indices, but just dont want to read it till your loading is complete. Is that correct understanding? Also, what kind of writes are we talking about here? Intraday updates or end of day bulk updates?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Once the data loading in the new index is done, I would delete the old index and want the new index only to service the reads. Check my answer on this question.

Comment: Also, your solution doesn't support a real-time scenario and assumes that configuration of the writing party can be changed at will (to change the index where data is supposed to be written). That's not always possible.

Comment: You need to be clear on your requirement. Are you try to do this for real time or batch load. You are talking about deleting the index, which you wouldn't be doing for real time write scenario for every request.So please specify what kind of writes are you performing? If its for batch overnight loads, using separate alias is the way to go. For intraday updates, i would use the same alias as what I use for read. Only for nightly reloads, use the alternate alias and swap it out, once loading is complete.

Comment: You are free to make bad choices :) Now all your writes have an additional filtering overhead, which isn't there with separate alias. Filtered alias is geared towards creating views for reads. Not meant for writes. But you can use it, if you want to.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand it at all. The filter I create is for reads, not writes. The filter in my answer isn't a write filter - you can write to the alias and Elastic will write the documents to it without paying heed to the filter. The filter creates a view for reads and that's exactly what I want. 

Why would I create a write filter (if such a thing exists) when I'm trying to restrict reads?

Comment: Ok. But I think that your reads will now suffer as it will still attempt to read from the index that you are writing (as internally, its only applying a filter to exclude records based on your filter condition in run time). So if you are data loads are high volume, your reads will suffer when bulk load is happening. You can try running an explain on your read query. If you are having very small volume of data, then it shouldn't matter.

Comment: That's quite possible, yes. I wouldn't say the data volume is particularly high or low, but I can say that reads are going to be less efficient. But, the data loading takes not more than say 30 minutes, so I'm fine with it. But yeah, I'll have to benchmark and run an explain to understand the exact impact.

Comment: I definitely prefer the read/write alias approach that @askids suggests here. The filter in the accepted answer is not being used as intended from what I can tell and seems hacky. Separate read/write aliases solves the problem of reindexing live data tidily without any downtime for end users and without misusing read filters to throw every request out for an index.